# Prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+f^2(x)} <\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)$ is a decreasing function, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)>0$. Prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+f^2(x)} <\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}$.

Attempt: I tried $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, $g(0)=0,$ we need to get a relation with $g(1)$ but I'm not able to relate this with the integral in any way. All I can conclude is that $g(x)$ is an increasing function from quotient rule and $f''(x)<0$. Had the integral been negative conclusion would have followed, but it isn't the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that $f^2(x)$ means $(f(x))^2$.

Let $f(x)=x(1-x)\geq 0$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Then, $f'(x)=1-2x$ which is a decreasing function, $f(0)=0$, and $f'(0)=1>0$.
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+f^2(x)}>0 $$
since the integrand is positive but $\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}=\frac{0}{-1}=0$. On the other hand, if you try with $f(x)=x(3-x)$ then the inequality is true in the given direction.

Comment: You are right. It works only if both $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are positive.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, OP might have meant $f'(1)>0$ instead.

Comment: Apologies. But in my book it is given just as what I have written. Might be there is some error in the question. What should I do with this question now?

Comment: @user600016 As Martin R pointed out, it works if both $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are positive. Otherwise, it's not necessarily true as my example shows. You can pick $f(1)=0$ to make it false. Or $f'(1)=0$ to make the ratio $f(1)/f'(1)$ undefined. If this is a homework problem, you can tell your instructor there's an issue.

Comment: @user600016: We trivially have $0 < \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+f^2(x)} \le 1$, and $f(0) = 0$ together with the concavity implies $f'(1) \le f(1)$. Which means that the desired conclusion is easily obtained (but not very interesting) as soon as $f'(1) > 0$. I wonder what the purpose of that exercise is.